# What is a CRUD system?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am learning Event Sourcing in my spare time.  I see lots of references to 'CRUD type systems' online.  I understand a CRUD type system to be:

1) A database driven system (website or application) i.e. a system that supports creates, reads, updates and deletes.  A domain model is not needed in this case.

or

2) A system that "should" (a bit opinionated) have a domain model, however all the domain logic is contained inside application services I.e. the domain model is anemic.

However, recently I have read references to systems that do not use Event Sourcing as CRUD.  For example, if I implemented CQRS with a reltional database on the write side (not an event log) and MongoDB on the read side, then is this a CRUD system?

What exactly is meant by a CRUD system? Does this depend on who I talk to?

Comment: I don't really know if that's helping, but I used to say CRUD referring to web applications which have little to no extra value other than providing an UI to a database table. As Doc Brown suggests I suppose the meaning is context dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this depend on who I talk to?

Yes

> What exactly is meant by a CRUD system?

[Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/379070/199871) has the right idea - a crud system is just domain agnostic storage.  That might mean durable storage (on disk, or in a database), or ephemeral storage (the models that we use in memory).

*In the context of CQRS and Event Sourcing*, the term is often use to distinguish problems where the benefits of separate reads and rights (CQRS) and temporal query support (Event Sourcing) won't offset the extra complexity those patterns introduce.

The point being if the intention is simply to store somebody else's data (saving files where we never look at the contents, or caching local copies of data where the book of record is outside of your system), then we should consider carefully the benefits of solving the problem with simple technologies.

For example: consider the source history of your project -- are temporal queries important there?  yes, absolutely.  So it may be worth having a detailed history of everything that is happening.  But does your package manager care about the historical details of hello-world-1.0.0 ?  Not so much.

Comment: If you are starting a new system and using principles from DDD, then should you always use Event Sourcing instead of CRUD?

Comment: +1 for the reference to temporal queries.

Answer (score 4):

CRUD is an acronym for Create, Read, Update, Delete, the four fundamental operations of a database system, and *that's all it is.*

I suppose you could describe a system as *CRUD-like.*  Where I currently work we are having ongoing discussions about this, because the existing system is very database-operation-centric, and while this is very convenient for the programmers, it's not of much help to the users, who are working in a business domain and would prefer a workflow-style application that is tailored to their business operations instead of thinking about adding to and deleting records from a database.

**Further Reading**
[Create, read, update and delete on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)

Comment: +1 for the reference to workflows.  If a system does not use event sourcing and is built with a rich domain model then does that make it CRUD? I believe the answer is no.

Comment: Those concepts are unrelated.  You can have a data access layer that works in a CRUD-like fashion and still have a rich domain model and event sourcing.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you are saying that the resistance of event sourcing is irrelevant when describing a system as crud or not.

Comment: The only thing that needs to be present to describe a "system" as CRUD (for some arbitrary definition of "system") are the operations Create, Read, Update and Delete.

Comment: If a system uses an event log/event store on the write side (append only) and nosql on the read side then I guess it could be described as non CRUD.

Comment: While it's true that a data access layer can itself be CRUD-like, IMO, when people refer to the whole *application* as CRUD-like (or CRUDy), it usually means that it's very database-centric, with a domain model that is not rich, or no domain model at all (basically, I'd say that the two meanings OP listed are about right). In both cases, regardless of what "should" be, it's how the problem is actually solved that makes it CRUDy or not. Essentially, the whole logic is primarily centered around the four operations, with data traveling from the DB up and down the layers in every usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

CRUD is short for [Create/Read/Update/Delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) capability.  It is using [problem domain naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_domain) rather than programming domain naming which is preferable as best practice.

Functions with those name are usually public methods on [Data Access Object (DAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and will roughly map on to SQL programming domain of Insert/Select/Update/Delete.